# Elasticsearch and Laravel scout-elasticsearch-driver return an empty response

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

**First i use scout-elasticsearch-driver for Laravel Scout**: https://github.com/babenkoivan/scout-elasticsearch-driver

I followed step by step the readme, create the index, migrate the index, configure a mapping and `User::search()->get()` returns an empty array.

***Obviously my database is migrated and populated.***

**I would like to search a user by:**

- His ***first_name***
- His ***last_name***
- His ***nick_name***

So i have created an **IndexConfigurator**:

```php
class UserIndexConfigurator extends IndexConfigurator
{
   use Migratable;

   /**
   * @var array
   */
   protected $settings = [
     //
   ];
}
```

Created a **SearchRule**:

```php
class UserSearchRule extends SearchRule
{
   public function buildQueryPayload()
   {
       $query = $this->builder->query;

       return [
          'should' => [
              [
                'match' => [
                   'first_name' => [
                              'query' => $query
                          ]
                      ]
                  ],
                  [
                      'match' => [
                          'last_name' => [
                              'query' => $query
                          ]
                      ]
                  ],
                  [
                      'match' => [
                          'nick_name' => [
                              'query' => $query
                          ]
                      ]
                  ]
              ]
          ];
   }
}
```

Configured my **User Model** accordingly:

```php
<?php
class User extends Authenticatable

  {
    useSearchable;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $indexConfigurator = UserIndexConfigurator::class;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $searchRules = [UserSearchRule::class ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $mapping = ['properties' => ['first_name' => ['type' => 'text'], 'last_name' => ['type' => 'text'], 'nick_name' => ['type' => 'text'], ]];
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'nick_name', ];
  }
```

Do i missed something?

**EDIT 1:**
***Result of curl request to elasticsearch cluster***

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/user/_search?pretty=true&q=*:*"
```

[image: curl -XGET on http://localhost:9200]

**EDIT 2:**

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/user?pretty=true"
```

[image: actual mapping of the user index]

**Print of the query that this produced by:**

```
dd(User::search('lo')->explain());
```

[image: explain the elastic search request]

**EDIT 3**
***Laravel scout and elasticsearch driver configuration:***

*scout_elastic.php*

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

return [
    'client' => [
        'hosts' => [
            env('SCOUT_ELASTIC_HOST', 'localhost:9200'),
        ],
    ],
    'update_mapping' => env('SCOUT_ELASTIC_UPDATE_MAPPING', true),
    'indexer' => env('SCOUT_ELASTIC_INDEXER', 'single'),
    'document_refresh' => env('SCOUT_ELASTIC_DOCUMENT_REFRESH', 'wait_for'),
];
```

*scout.php*

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Search Engine
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default search connection that gets used while
    | using Laravel Scout. This connection is used when syncing all models
    | to the search service. You should adjust this based on your needs.
    |
    | Supported: "algolia", "null", "elastic"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('SCOUT_DRIVER', 'elastic'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Index Prefix
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify a prefix that will be applied to all search index
    | names used by Scout. This prefix may be useful if you have multiple
    | "tenants" or applications sharing the same search infrastructure.
    |
    */

    'prefix' => env('SCOUT_PREFIX', ''),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Data Syncing
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows you to control if the operations that sync your data
    | with your search engines are queued. When this is set to "true" then
    | all automatic data syncing will get queued for better performance.
    |
    */

    'queue' => env('SCOUT_QUEUE', true),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Chunk Sizes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options allow you to control the maximum chunk size when you are
    | mass importing data into the search engine. This allows you to fine
    | tune each of these chunk sizes based on the power of the servers.
    |
    */

    'chunk' => [
        'searchable' => 500,
        'unsearchable' => 500,
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Soft Deletes
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option allows to control whether to keep soft deleted records in
    | the search indexes. Maintaining soft deleted records can be useful
    | if your application still needs to search for the records later.
    |
    */

    'soft_delete' => false,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Algolia Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your Algolia settings. Algolia is a cloud hosted
    | search engine which works great with Scout out of the box. Just plug
    | in your application ID and admin API key to get started searching.
    |
    */

    'algolia' => [
        'id' => env('ALGOLIA_APP_ID', ''),
        'secret' => env('ALGOLIA_SECRET', ''),
    ],

];
```

**EDIT 4: Updated elasticsearch mapping**

```sh
php artisan elastic:update-mapping App\\Models\\User
```

*Gives:*

```
{
  "user" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "user_write" : { }
    },
    "mappings" : {
      "users" : {
        "properties" : {
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "id" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          },
          "nick_name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1552675390883",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "hdtsA8ncQNC8rrI5Tr853A",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6050499"
        },
        "provided_name" : "user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the mapping for your index.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena thanks for reply, but `protected $mapping` in my `User` model it is not the mapping of my index?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i must have gleamed over it. It looks good to me. Can you print the elastic DSL query that gets generated through your code. Your mapping in the code looks good, but just to make sure that the actual index you are querying has the same mapping, can you post the response of `curl -XGET host:9200/user_index`?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena thanks for reply, it's ok, see my edit :)

Comment: Hey, this doesn't tell me much. Try `curl -XGET host:9200/user` This should give you the actual mapping of the index. What you added is the result of search. 
Also, can you print the query that this produces `User::search()->get()`?

Comment: @ArchitSaxena thanks again for helping me, seed my second edit

Comment: I think there's some problem with how you've setup scout. On going through the documentation it seems that scout ships with Algolia driver by default. I am assuming you added some driver for elasticsearch? The query that you printed doesn't look like an elasticsearch DSL query (only the `hits._payload.body` part is relevant). Also, i don't understand why `curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/user?pretty=true"` returned `mappings: {}`. All of it points to the fact that there's some problem with how scout is configured because it can't seem to communicate with elasticsearch.

Comment: You'll need to post what engine and it's configuration (if any) that you added, specific to elasticsearch. I haven't used scout or Laravel before, but i can take a look.

Comment: i have updated my post with the config files.

Comment: @ArchitSaxena by running `php artisan elastic:update-mapping App\\Models\\User` the mapping was updated, see my fourth update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution was to update the `UserSearchRule`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Models\SearchRules;

use ScoutElastic\SearchRule;

/**
 * Class UserSearchRule
 *
 * @package App\Models\SearchRules
 */
class UserSearchRule extends SearchRule
{

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function buildQueryPayload()
    {
        $query = $this->builder->query;

        return [
            'must'  => [
                'multi_match'   => [
                    'query'     => $query,
                    'fields'    => ['first_name', 'last_name', 'nick_name'],
                    'type'      => 'phrase_prefix',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: it's works. Great.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the answer but doesn't work on my end.

If the answer doesnt work, we can do this manually and get the hit results.

```
   $query = request()->has('q') ? request('q') : '*';
   $results = Product::search($query)->raw()['hits'];
   $products = collect($results['hits'])->pluck('_source');
```